# Holomorphic map from a punctured affine line to $M_g$ with Zariski-dense image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-spaces

Denote by $M_g$ the coarse moduli space of connected smooth projective complex curves of genus $g$. Is there a holomorphic map $U\to M_g$ with Zariski-dense image where $U$ is the affine line with finitely many points removed?

For $2 \leq g\leq 14$ there is a dominant rational map $\mathbb{A}^{3g-3}\to M_g$ which can be composed with the map $\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^{3g-3}$ given by $z\to \big (e^z, e^{e^z}, \dots \big)$.

We can construct a holomorphic map from a higher genus (possibly infinite genus, see the comments) Riemann surface to $M_g$ with Zariski-dense image. Since $M_g$ is irreducible quasi-projective there is an open immersion $M_g\to \overline{M_g}$ where $\overline{M_g}$ is an irreducible projective variety. By Noether normalization there is a finite surjective morphism $\overline{M_g}\to \mathbb{P}^{3g-3}$ so there is a dominant quasi-finite morphism $M_g\to\mathbb{P}^{3g-3}$. Base change the curve $\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{P}^{3g-3}$ by that to get the map.

Comment: Read up on Brody hyperbolicity. I guess $A_g$ and hence $M_g$ are Brody hyperbolic. Indeed, there should be no nonconstant holomorphic maps from $\mathbb{C}$ into the Siegel upper-half space.

Comment: By the way, is your second paragraph correct? You only have a rational map, it is not defined on the entire $\mathbb{A}^{3g-3}$, right?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger it is probably not defined on all of $\mathbb{A}^{3g-3}$ but the locus where it is not defined is closed so it can only have finitely many intersections with the curve.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I think Brody hyperbolicity is specifically about the affine line, it can not be used to rule out the existence of a map from the affine line with 20 points removed (as far as I understand).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: @vrz "it is probably not defined on all of $\mathbb{A}^{3g-3}$ but the locus where it is not defined is closed so it can only have finitely many intersections with the curve."  The curve you describe is highly transcendental, so it could well have infinitely many intersection points, accumulating at infinity.

Comment: @JasonStarr in general you are correct but for this specific curve I think it is ok. Think about it: we have a polynomial in $e^z$, $e^{e^z}$ and so on that should have infinitely many zeroes. But whichever highest tower of exponents has a non-zero coefficient in it is going to dominate its values for $|z|$ larger than some fixed value so all the zeroes lie in some disk. Within that disk, if it had infinitely many zeroes there would be an accumulation point so it would have to identically vanish.

Comment: Did you ask and then delete a very closely related question?

Comment: @WillSawin yes I did (thanks for your suggestion by the way).

Comment: Minor nitpick: Mg is not Brody hyperbolic, the coarse space contains projective lines by a construction of Oort. Think of A1; this is is om to the affine line. These spaces are hyperbolic as stacks tho.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I am having a cognitive dissonance. So is it true that if a smooth projective variety is Brody hyperbolic then any holomorphic map from an affine curve to it is algebraic? Because if that is true the argument in my last paragraph should be completely wrong (as it applies to any such variety).

Comment: Yes that’s true. You don’t need smoothness nor projectivity, just properness. Have a look at my arXiv link for more details and a statement in the non proper case (replace Brody hyperbolic by “hyperbolically embaddable”)

Comment: Concerning your last paragraph: you are pulling back a highly transcendental map along a finite morphism. There is no reason for the resulting complex analytic space to be an algebraic curve. Think of what happens when you pull back a finite cover of the affine line along the exponential

Comment: PS. The arXiv link is the one I posted as a comment to your other question.